# Computing the hit and miss ratio of a cache organized as either direct mapped or two-way associative

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

This is an example problem in a computer organization and architecture course that's giving me some trouble. It goes as follows:

> Consider a cache of 4 lines of 16 bytes each. Main memory is divided
>   into blocks of 16 bytes each. That is, block 0 has bytes with
>   addresses 0 through 15, and so on. Now consider a program that
>   accesses memory in the following sequence of addresses:
>
> Once: 63-70
>
> Loop 10 times: 15-32; 80-95
>
> a. Suppose the cache is organized as direct mapped. Memory blocks 0,
>   4, and so on are assigned to line 1; blocks 1, 5, and so on to line 2;
>   and so on. Compute the hit ratio.
>
> b. Suppose the cache is organized as two-way set associative, with two
>   sets of two lines each. Even-numbered blocks are assigned to set 0 and
>   odd-numbered blocks are assigned to set 1. Compute the hit ratio using
>   the least recently used replacement scheme.

I know that the formula for finding the hit ratio is:

`hit ratio = hits / (hits + misses)`

and that the LRU replacement scheme should be used for both **a** and **b**, since it's the most efficient. I know how to find and compute addresses in a cache, but this has me stumped.

Any help in understanding this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider a cache of 4 lines of 16 bytes each. Main memory is divided
>   into blocks of 16 bytes each. That is, block 0 has bytes with
>   addresses 0 through 15, and so on.

Number of cache lines = 4

Each cache line = 16 bytes

Main memory block size = 16 bytes

Block 0 holds address 0 to 15,Block 1 holds address 16 to 31,Block 2 holds address 32 to 47, etc as below

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║       Main Memory        ║
╠════════════════╤═════════╣
║ Memory address │         ║
╟────────────────┼─────────╢
║       0        │ Block 0 ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       1        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       2        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       3        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       4        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       5        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       6        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       7        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       8        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       9        │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       10       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       11       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       12       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       13       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       14       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       15       │         ║
╟────────────────┼─────────╢
║       16       │ Block 1 ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       17       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║       18       │         ║
╟────────────────┤         ║
║   and so on    │         ║
╚════════════════╧═════════╝
```

> Now consider a program that accesses memory in the following sequence
>   of addresses:
>
> Once: 63-70
>
> Loop 10 times: 15-32; 80-95

Here its not correctly specified that-

**Case 1 :** looped 15-32 ten times and then looped 80-95 ten times

**Case 2 :** 15-32 and 80-95 are looped one after another ten times

anyway we'll solve both cases.

> **a.** Suppose the cache is organized as direct mapped. Memory blocks 0,
>   4, and so on are assigned to line 1; blocks 1, 5, and so on to line 2;
>   and so on. Compute the hit ratio.

Direct mapped Cache :

```
╔═════════════╤═══════════════════╤═════════════════════════╗
║ Cache lines │ Main memory block │ Addresses in each block ║
╠═════════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════════════════════╣
║      0      │      Block 0      │          0-15           ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║      1      │      Block 1      │          16-31          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║      2      │      Block 2      │          32-47          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║      3      │      Block 3      │          48-63          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║      0      │      Block 4      │          64-79          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║      1      │      Block 5      │          80-95          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║      2      │      Block 6      │         96-111          ║
╚═════════════╧═══════════════════╧═════════════════════════╝
```

Accessing memory:

(1) once: 63-70

63 falls in Block 3 - Miss on 63 (Block 3 is bought to cache)

64 falls in Block 4 - Miss on 64 (Block 4 is bought to cache)

```
╔═════════════╤═══════════════════╤═════════╗
║ Cache lines │ Main memory Block │ Address ║
╠═════════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════╣
║      0      │      Block 4      │  64-79  ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      1      │         -         │    -    ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      2      │         -         │    -    ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      3      │      Block 3      │  48-63  ║
╚═════════════╧═══════════════════╧═════════╝
```

therefore, 2 miss and 6 hit.

(2) loop: 15-32,80-95

Case 1:

15 falls in Block 0 - Miss on 15 (Block 0 is bought to cache, replacing Block 4)

16 falls in Block 1 - Miss on 16 (Block 1 is bought to cache)

32 falls in Block 2 - Miss on 32 (Block 2 is bought to cache)

```
╔═════════════╤═══════════════════╤═════════╗
║ Cache lines │ Main memory Block │ Address ║
╠═════════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════╣
║      0      │      Block 0      │  0-15   ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      1      │      Block 1      │  16-31  ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      2      │      Block 2      │  32-47  ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      3      │      Block 3      │  48-63  ║
╚═════════════╧═══════════════════╧═════════╝
```

80 falls in Block 5 - Miss on 80 (Block 5 is bought to cache, replacing Block 1)

```
╔═════════════╤═══════════════════╤═════════╗
║ Cache lines │ Main memory Block │ Address ║
╠═════════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════╣
║      0      │      Block 0      │  0-15   ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      1      │      Block 5      │  80-95  ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      2      │      Block 2      │  32-47  ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────╢
║      3      │      Block 3      │  48-63  ║
╚═════════════╧═══════════════════╧═════════╝
```

therefore, 4 miss and 29 hit.

Case 2 : loop: 15-32,80-95

**{{** 15 falls in Block 0 - Miss on 15 (Block 0 is bought to cache, replacing Block 4)

16 falls in Block 1 - Miss on 16 (Block 1 is bought to cache)

32 falls in Block 2 - Miss on 32 (Block 2 is bought to cache)

80 falls in Block 5 - Miss on 80 (Block 5 is bought to cache, replacing Block 1) **}} x 1 times**

**{{** 16 falls in Block 1 - Miss on 16 (Block 1 is bought to cache, replacing Block 5)

80 falls in Block 5 - Miss on 80 (Block 5 is bought to cache, replacing Block 1) **}} x 9 times**

therefore, 22 miss and 11 hit.

> **b.** Suppose the cache is organized as two-way set associative, with two
>   sets of two lines each. Even-numbered blocks are assigned to set 0 and
>   odd-numbered blocks are assigned to set 1. Compute the hit ratio using
>   the least recently used replacement scheme.

Two-way set associative mapping:

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║            Cache            ║
╠═════════════╤═══════╤═══════╣
║ Cache lines │ Set 1 │ Set 2 ║
╟─────────────┼───────┼───────╢
║      0      │   -   │   -   ║
╟─────────────┼───────┼───────╢
║      1      │   -   │   -   ║
╚═════════════╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Block allocation to cache lines:

```
╔═════════════╤═══════════════════╗
║ Cache lines │ Main memory Block ║
╠═════════════╪═══════════════════╣
║      0      │  Block 0,2,4,..   ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────────╢
║      1      │  Block 1,3,5,..   ║
╚═════════════╧═══════════════════╝
```

Accessing memory:

(1) once: 63-70

63 falls in Block 3 - Miss on 63 (Block 3 is bought to cache)

64 falls in Block 4 - Miss on 64 (Block 4 is bought to cache)

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╗
║             Cache             ║
╠═════════════╤═════════╤═══════╣
║ Cache lines │  Set 1  │ Set 2 ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼───────╢
║      0      │ Block 4 │   -   ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼───────╢
║      1      │ Block 3 │   -   ║
╚═════════════╧═════════╧═══════╝
```

therefore, 2 miss and 6 hit.

(2) loop: 15-32,80-95

Case 1:

15 falls in Block 0 - Miss on 15 (Block 0 is bought to cache)

16 falls in Block 1 - Miss on 16 (Block 1 is bought to cache)

32 falls in Block 2 - Miss on 32 (Block 2 is bought to cache, replacing Block 4)

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╗
║              Cache              ║
╠═════════════╤═════════╤═════════╣
║ Cache lines │  Set 1  │  Set 2  ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼─────────╢
║      0      │ Block 2 │ Block 0 ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼─────────╢
║      1      │ Block 3 │ Block 1 ║
╚═════════════╧═════════╧═════════╝
```

80 falls in Block 5 - Miss on 80 (Block 5 is bought to cache, replacing Block 3)

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╗
║              Cache              ║
╠═════════════╤═════════╤═════════╣
║ Cache lines │  Set 1  │  Set 2  ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼─────────╢
║      0      │ Block 2 │ Block 0 ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼─────────╢
║      1      │ Block 5 │ Block 1 ║
╚═════════════╧═════════╧═════════╝
```

therefore, 4 miss and 29 hit.

Case 2 : loop: 15-32,80-95

15 falls in Block 0 - Miss on 15 (Block 0 is bought to cache)

16 falls in Block 1 - Miss on 16 (Block 1 is bought to cache)

32 falls in Block 2 - Miss on 32 (Block 2 is bought to cache,, replacing Block 2)

80 falls in Block 5 - Miss on 80 (Block 5 is bought to cache, replacing Block 5)

therefore, 4 miss and 29 hit.

**Answer:**

**a.**

**Case 1:** hit ratio = (6+29)/(8+18+15) * 100 = 85.3%

**Case 2:** hit ratio = (6+11)/(8+18+15) * 100 = 41.1%

**b.**

**Case 1:** hit ratio = (6+29)/(8+18+15) * 100 = 85.3%

**Case 2:** hit ratio = (6+29)/(8+18+15) * 100 = 85.3%